# Make every thing in Lilypond larger

Tags: lilypond

How can I make every thing in Lilypond bigger, I want the size of all objects (e.g. note heads, accidentals, clefs etc.) to become bigger. Can any one help?

Answer (score 2):

If the only thing you want to keep the same is the staff line distance I’d use a larger default size and then reduce the staff space correspondingly:

```
#(set-global-staff-size (* 20 1.2))

\layout {
  \context {
    \Staff
    \override StaffSymbol.staff-space = #(/ 1 1.2)
  }
}

{ c' d' e' es' des'  }
```

Else you may adjust the `font-size` property of all grobs you want to adjust (as long as these follow the font interface).